# Why is the bootstrap icon on the left and not the right?

Tags: laravel, icons, position, bootstrap-5, right-to-left

Why is the bootstrap icon on the left and not the right

Meanwhile, on the bootstrap page, the icon appears on the right

How to set and change it

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfwTX.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMj8X.png)

I want the end result to be like this
[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXaxA.png)
and
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxZLD.png)

my code :

```
<div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" id="username" placeholder="Username" required value="{{ old('username') }}">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                @error('username') 
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  {{ $message }}
                </div>
                @enderror
</div>
```

and the second

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" dir="ltr">
        @if(session()->has('success'))
          {{ session('success') }}
          @endif
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>

...
   </div>
</div>
```

i use laravel and bootstrap